# Is $A^2$ the same thing as $A^TA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume A is a matrix.  Is $A^2$ the same thing as $A^TA$?  I keep on seeing $A^2$ but it's tough to find a walkthrough of calculating $A^2$.

Comment: They are not. $A^T$ is for transpose of $A$ (switching roles of rows and columns). In fact for $A^TA$ to be defined we don't need $A$ to be a square matrix. But for $A^2$ to be defined, $A$ must be a square matrix. To learn about matrix multiplication try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: $A^2$ is just $A$ multiplied by itself.

Comment: It is obviously true if $A$ is a Symmetric matrix

Comment: Why do you find it easier to calculate $A^TA$ than to calculate $A^2 = AA$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample:

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. We have:

$$
A^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\not=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= A^T A
$$

And also
$$
A^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\not=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= AA^T
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ over your favorite field $k.$ Observe that there are $m$ rows and $n$ columns of $A.$ We will denote by $a_{ij}$ the entry of the $i$th row and $j$th column of $A$ for any pair of integers $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq n.$ By definition, the entry of the matrix $B = A^T$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column is given by $b_{ij} = a_{ji},$ i.e., the matrix $A^T$ is the matrix $A$ whose rows and columns are swapped. Consequently, there are $n$ rows and $m$ columns of $B = A^T,$ i.e., $A^T$ is an $n \times m$ matrix.

We can multiply two matrices $A$ and $B$ to obtain a matrix $AB$ if and only if the number of rows of $A$ is equal to the number of columns of $B.$ Likewise, we can obtain the matrix $BA$ if and only if the number of rows of $B$ is equal to the number of columns of $A.$ Consequently, the matrices $A^T A$ and $AA^T$ both make sense; however, the matrix $AA = A^2$ makes sense if and only if $A$ has as many rows as columns, i.e., if and only if $m = n.$ We refer to such a matrix as a *square* matrix.

Ultimately, this observation implies that $A^T A$ and $A^2$ are in general different objects: one always exists, but the other might not. But as mentioned in the comments, there are examples for which $A^T A = A^2.$ For instance, if $A$ is a *symmetric* matrix, then by definition, we have that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$ so that $A^T = A,$ and therefore, it follows that $A^T A = AA = A^2 = AA = AA^T.$

Computing the matrix $A^2$ amounts to carrying out the matrix multiplication $AA.$ By definition, if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, the entry of the $k$th row and $\ell$th column of $A^2 = AA$ is given by the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ki} a_{i \ell}.$ Given that the $k$th row of $A$ is $(a_{k1} \, a_{k2} \, \cdots \, a_{kn})$ and the $\ell$th column of $A$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} a_{1 \ell} \\ a_{2 \ell} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n \ell} \end{pmatrix},$$ the entry of the $k$th row and $\ell$th column of $A^2$ is $a_{k 1} a_{1 \ell} + a_{k 2} a_{2 \ell} + \cdots + a_{k n} a_{n \ell}.$